# Objective C locationManager cannot get current location, always returns 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

Can you please review following code, it did tries locationManager with delegates, and tries to return current location of device.

But always returns 0 (allowed location permission)

.m

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}


CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {
  // TODO: Handle status authorized always


} else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
  // TODO: Handle status not determined


} else {
  // TODO: Handle other
}






- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

  //NSLog(@"newLocation: %@", newLocation);

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    //NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);

}
```

info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>We would like to use your location.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We would like to use your location.</string>
```

Comment: Do you have a strong reference to your locationManager?

Comment: Yes @property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
declared on .h

Comment: What do you mean by return 0?

Comment: are you run on   simulator ?

Comment: didUpdateToLocation is deprecated, you should be using didUpdateLocations instead

Comment: I mean returning 0 == latitude and longtitude values

Comment: Tested on both simulator and device.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to call startUpdatingLocation after requestAlwaysAuthorization.  and use below didUpdateLocations delegate methods.

```
if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

        _currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0]; 
        //do your stuff with the location

    }
```

For Simulator Testing -  Select Simulator and goto Debug ->Location -> Apple or City Run

For Device Testing Please check with map if you are getting current location or not . Sometime device not getting current location due to inside of house.